# Calling a Javascript member function of an object named in a variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following so-called *Revealing Module Pattern* and I want to call the function **a** inside function **b** using a variable. How can I do that?

```
foo = function() {
    a = function() {
    };

    b = function() {
        memberName = 'a';
        // Call a() using value stored in variable `memberName`.
    }

    return {b: b};
}();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `a` is not a member, but a variable (and it should be a local one!). You cannot access those dynamically by name unless you use dark magic (`eval`).

You will need to make it a member of an object, so that you can access it by bracket notation:

```
var foo = (function() {
    var members = {
        a: function() { }
    };

    function b() {
        var memberName = 'a';
        members[memberName].call();
    }

    return {b: b};
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = function() {
    var inner = {
      a : function() {
      }
    };

    b = function() {
        memberName = 'a';
        // Call a() using value stored in variable `memberName`.
        inner[memberName]();
    }

    return {b: b};
}();
```